# I uploaded wordpress via ftp, but it didn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_bloginfo() in /home/name/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-locale.php on line 233

line 233

```
if ( 'rtl' === $this->text_direction && strpos( get_bloginfo( 'version' ), '-src' ) ) {
        $this->text_direction = 'ltr';
        add_action( 'all_admin_notices', array( $this, 'rtl_src_admin_notice' ) );
    }
```

Comment: Something fairly important didnt get uploaded I would say

Comment: Please check your `general-template.php` file in this path `/wp-includes/general-template.php`, You may need to re-upload this file. And if this file have not been uploaded completely, then maybe you need to re-upload all of your wordpress files as well!

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's very unusual........sometimes for hours it creates no errors...and sometines creates errors in every seconds........I don't know what creates this error.

Comment: @EhsanT I already uploaded it via wordpress.

Comment: If sometimes you are getting this error and other times you do not, Then maybe there is something wrong with your hosting provider i guess! If during the times which you are getting this error, you view the source of `/wp-includes/general-template.php` file, then what will you see? can you find `get_bloginfo()` function in it?

Comment: @EhsanT this is get_bloginfo() function

Comment: When you wrote it acts unusual and there are times it's working and times it's not working, I figured out that there's nothing wrong with your file and you have the function in it. So I think since it's happening randomly, It's hard to find the origin of you problem. Maybe you can check your server error log.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some files are missed during the upload.

**You must never change core files** because as a new wordpress update comes up, you'll get in trouble again.

Best thing to do is to temporarily comment (or delete) that line:

```
// if ( 'rtl' === $this->text_direction && strpos( get_bloginfo( 'version' ), '-src' ) ) {
//   $this->text_direction = 'ltr';
//   add_action( 'all_admin_notices', array( $this, 'rtl_src_admin_notice' ) );
// }
```

And after that you can access wp-admin page. then go to `Dashboard -> Updates -> Re-install Now`

This is the safest solution for this problem. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. simply remove get_bloginfo from line 233 in wp-includes/class-wp-locale.php
and no more PHP fatal error......thanks to myself :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this info. But this is not an answer, You can easily edit your question and add these data to your post as an update to your question.

Comment: @EhsanT I know this is not an answer. I couldn't paste the code in comment box.I think you were right. something wrong with server from hosting provider company. this is my last error log.  "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction در پایگاه‌داده وردپرس برای دستور INSERT INTO `wp_options`"

Comment: This answer works temporarily but it's not safe. NEVER CHANGE CORE FILES

Answer (score 0):

my MySQL server service was down...